# How to change font size using VBA in MS Acces

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm trying to change font size in Ms Access report in section group based on text box value.

I have wrote some code in VBA in event "On Format":

```
Private Sub Header_OrganizationalUnit_Format(Cancel As Integer, FormatCount As Integer)
    If Me.txt_OrganizationalUnit.Value = "HeadQuarter" Then
        Me.txt_OrganizationalUnit.FontSize = 24
    Else
        Me.txt_OrganizationalUnit.FontSize = 12
    End If
End Sub
```

It doesn't change any font size in text box

Comment: it will need to be in the textbox's events, `change` maybe, not in access at mo.  Or the report open events?

Comment: This should work for Print Preview. Do you perhaps open the report in Report View?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you don't need VBA in order to do this. You can use conditional formatting instead.

The event you want to capture is the `Change` event.
You also need to read the `Text` property instead of `Value`, since the value is only updated when the textbox loses focus.

Add this event procedure to your report code:

```
Private Sub txt_OrganizationalUnit_Change()
    With txt_OrganizationalUnit
        If .Text = "HeadQuarter" Then
            .FontSize = 24
        Else
            .FontSize = 12
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Using `with` block allows you to reduce the number of bound calls VB performs in the background, while making your code look better.
[image: Added in edit: The Change event is here alright.]

Comment: It is Report not form

Comment: Oh, sorry. Edited my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yet, the event fires nonetheless.

Comment: You may also open the events dropdown for `txt_OrganizationalUnit` in the VBE IDE and see that `Change` is definitely in there. Clicking on it will create a stub `Private Sub txt_OrganizationalUnit_Change()` for you to fill.

Comment: I edited the post to include a picture showing the `Change` event.

Comment: As I said this is report. I want to format Font in this specific field based on value. Event OnChange triggers when changes are made in text box, in report wit this specific situation it is impossible.

Comment: Look, just follow these steps, please...
1. Copy the code I supplied.
2. Paste the code *instead* of the code you currently have (`Private Sub Header_OrganizationalUnit_Format`)
3. Run your form and type "HeadQuarter" in `txt_OrganizationalUnit`.
4. Enjoy.

Comment: I am sorry but I did not present the problem precisely enough. The option you presented works, of course, but in the "print prewiew" view. I will use my report as one of the elements of the form. However, thank you for your help and best regards.